# Augmenting dispatch causes unstable identity

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm augmenting Context's dispatch function like this:

```
const augmentDispatch = (
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<Action | ApiAction>,
  state: AppState,
) => (action: Thunk | Action | ApiAction) => {
  if (typeof action === "object" && action.type === CALL_API) {
    return callApi(action as ApiAction, dispatch);
  }

  return action instanceof Function
    ? action(dispatch, state)
    : dispatch(action as Action);
};
```

It allows me to trigger an API call for certain actions. I then use it like this:

```
export function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(rootReducer, defaultState);

  const augmentedDispatch = augmentDispatch(dispatch, state);

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{ state, dispatch: augmentedDispatch }}
    >
```

This works great for event handlers, but I ran into an infinite re-render when I attempted to use it in `useEffect`:

```
export const EditForm: React.FC = () => {
  const { dispatch, state } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  const dispatchLoadDetails = useCallback(
    () => dispatch(loadDetails()),
    [dispatch],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatchLoadDetails();
  }, [dispatchLoadDetails]);

  return (
    <Form
```

I seem to have gotten around it by capturing a reference to the augmented dispatch:

```
export function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(rootReducer, defaultState);

  /**
   * Note the usage of useRef here - without it we'd generate a new reference to
   * augmentedDispatch with every call within useEffect, which would cause an
   * indfinite re-render
   */
  const augmentedDispatch = useRef(augmentDispatch(dispatch, state));

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{ state, dispatch: augmentedDispatch.current }}
    >
```

Is this the best way to solve this problem? The docs indicate `useRef` should be used as a last resort...

Comment: Are you sure it solves your problem?  If the `state` changes, `augmentedDispatch` won't be updated.

Comment: I don't need  `augmentedDispatch` to update.

Comment: So yes, that's the simplest way to solve it. You can dig in `react-redux` codebase and see how to solve it in a much more complicated way.